# Pattern matching in switch with empty curly braces

Tags: c#

I came over this piece of code:

```
return version switch
{
    { } s when s.Contains("v1") => ...,
    { } s when s.Contains("v2") => ...,
    { } s when s.Contains("v3") => ...,
    { } s when s.Contains("v4") => ..., 
    null => null,
    _ => null
}
```

I am not sure what exactly empty curly braces do here. I can't even google one single example of this. Is there any other reason besides shortening from:

```
return version switch
{
    string s when s.Contains("v1") => ...,
    string s when s.Contains("v2") => ...,
    string s when s.Contains("v3") => ...,
    string s when s.Contains("v4") => ..., 
    null => null,
    _ => null
}
```

Comment: When you use { } in a pattern, it matches any non-null object and allows you to apply conditions to that object.

{ } s when s.Contains("v1") => ... means  "match any non-null object (in this case, s) and check if s contains the substring "v1." If it does, execute the associated code.

The advantage of using this pattern is that it can be more concise when you want to apply a condition to a non-null object, and it's especially useful when you want to avoid repeating the same type check (e.g., string s) for multiple conditions.

Comment: `{}` is just a [property pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#property-pattern), but it does not contain any subpatterns. Therefore only null-checking is applied.